# javascript validating the whole form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Friends i am new to javascript, I am trying to write a script to validate the entire form whenever any input field value is changed of input fiels with the data attribute of required.
**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" class="inputField" data-required="true"></input>
<input type="text" name="MiddleName" class="inputField"></input>
<input type="text" name="LastName" class="inputField" data-required="true"></input>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var field, required, isValid, fieldVal;
function validatedForm() {
field = document.querySelectorAll('.inputField');
document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
var isValid = true;
for(var i=0; i < field.length; i++){
    required = field[i].dataset.required;       
    if(required){
        field[i].addEventListener('blur', function(e){
            fieldVal = this.value;
            if(fieldVal == ''){
                isValid = false;
            }
            checkSubmitBtn();
        }, true);
    }

}

function checkSubmitBtn() {
    if(isValid = true) {
        console.log(isValid);
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
    }
}
}
window.addEventListener("load", validatedForm);
```

**PROBLEM 1:**
The **isValid** is not updating hence even an empty blur on the input field makes the button disable to be false.

**PROBLEM 2:**
In case there are multiple forms on the page then how to validate only the desired forms .. just like in jQuery we add a script tag in the end to initialize the script according to it.

**PROBLEM 3:**
Is there a way to change the disable state of the button without the GetElementID ... I mean if that can be managed depending on the submit button of that particular form on the page where the script is suppose to work.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You check ```isValid = true``` , are you sure this you put the correct code ?

Comment: In checksubmi method condition is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like the following form validation..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var field, fieldVal, required = false;

    function validatedForm() {
        field = document.querySelectorAll('.inputField');
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;

        field.forEach(function(elem) {
            required = elem.dataset.required;
            if(required){
                elem.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
                    checkSubmitBtn(field);
                });
            }
        });     
    }

    function checkSubmitBtn(field) {
        var isDisabled = false;
        field.forEach(function(elem) {
            fieldVal = elem.value.trim();
            if(fieldVal == ''){
                isDisabled = true;
                return false;
            } 
        });

        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = isDisabled;
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", validatedForm);
</script>
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: your code is really great but no matter even if i fill all the fields the **isDisabled** still returns true and so the submit button remains disabled.

Comment: Have you checked it properly, if you fill all the fields the submit button is enabled after you click outside ('blur' event)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things going on here. First, your `checkSubmitBtn` function used a single `=` operator in the `if` statement. This won't actually check the variable, it instead will set the variable to that value. Here is the fixed function:

```
function checkSubmitBtn() {
    if (isValid == true) {
        document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

You mentioned not wanting to use `getElementById`. There are a few ways around this. One way would be to call the function once and store it in a variable to use later, like so:

```
var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

...

function checkSubmitBtn() {
    button.disabled = !isValid;
}
```

Another way would be to use jQuery. It still is technically calling `getElementById` in the backend, but the code is much simpler. If you wanted to avoid that, you also can still combine this with the technique I described above.

```
$("#submitButton").attr("disabled", !isValid);
```

I'd also like to point out that your code doesn't account for a situation where a form goes from invalid (starting point) to valid and back to invalid again. Say a user types in all of the fields but then backspaces everything. Your code will fall apart.

Lastly, your `<input>` HTML tags should not be closed. There are [certain tags](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html) that are considered "self-closing", i.e. you don't have to write the closing tag, `</input>`.